# Ar is missing after upgrade to Xcode 7

Tags: ios, c, xcode

I'm using Yosemite. Just upgraded Xcode 7 and command line

I'm getting this error when cross-compile C project for iOS.

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ar: No such file or directory

Comment: Have you searched the directory?  does the file actually exist?  if file exists, then update the list of directory paths to include the .../usr/bin directory  otherwise, search for the 'ar' executable and then update the directory paths accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Xcode 7.0` appears to have changed the default location for these tools:

```
nm
size
libtool
pagestuff
ar
codesign_allocate
dsymutil
install_name_tool
ld
ctf_insert
as
otool
strings
strip
redo_prebinding
lipo
nmedit
```

**Toolchain Location**:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/
```

It may not include all command line tools by default, so you can also try downloading them:

**[Command Line Tools OS X 10.10 for Xcode 7](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.10_for_Xcode_7/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.10_for_Xcode_7.dmg)**

The only tools now in the former location are:

```
texturetool
csent
unwinddump
dyldinfo
dsymutil-classic
rebase
pngcrush
dwarfdump
PackageApplication
iphoneos-optimize
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the issue!